# List entries to variables: ttk python

Tags: python, ttk

I am trying to shift the letters of a string over by 1 each time a while loop runs(so "A" becomes "B", "B" becomes "C" and so on each time through).

I need to have each result displayed so I can compare them.  What I don't want to do but know how to do is create 26 different functions each one shifting the letters one letter farther but this seems a bit ridiculous.

**How do I assign a variable to ttk each time the while loop goes through?**

I thought this would assign "ls" plus whatever the count was on (ls1, ls2, ls3...) to each variable but it does not.  It throws an error every time.

```
def shift1(*args):
    s = code.get()
    storage = []
    count = 1
    while (count <= 26):
        l = [ord(i) for i in s]
        sh = ([chr(i + count) for i in l])
        storage.append(sh)
        ("ls"+str(count)).set(storage(count - 1))
        count += 1
```

It give me an error that says

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'

Like I said I could just use this function 26 times each time assigning a diff ttk variable.

```
def shift1(*args):
    s = code.get()
    l = [ord(i) for i in s]
    sh1.set(''.join([chr(i + 1) for i in l]))
```

This will essentially bypass the loop, but I know there has to be a better way.
Very new to python and ttk so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it is more simple to just do a +1 on ASCII codes and then use mod operator to keep them in ASCII letter range.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I get the +1 on the ASCII code but not sure what you are talking about when you refer to "mod operator."  Not familiar with the terminology.  The code I have works for the shift, I just don't know how to get ttk to display each shift.  The only way I know to have a function assign a ttk variable is how I have done in the second block of code.  This doesn't work in the first bock because it needs to assign multiple variables so ttk will display each shift.  I'm kind of stuck and google is not helping.  I'm thinking I may have to make another fnc to assign the varbls

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to rotate the characters in a string around, assuming there are only A-Z letters in your string.

```
string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
for i in range(10):
    string = "".join([chr((ord(letter) - ord('A') + 1) % 26 + ord('A')) for letter in string])
    print string
```

The idea is that each letter has an ASCII code difference from the letter A. So letter A would be 0, letter B is 1. When letter Z is shifted forward, it needs to go back to A. This is where the modulo (%) comes in, it shifts the letter Z back to A if needed.

Output:

```
BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA
CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB
DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC
EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCD
FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDE
GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEF
HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFG
IJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGH
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHI
KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJ
```

Comment: I was beaten by a minute :(

Comment: Thanks this really helps me simplify it, but where I get lost is mapping out the variables to ttk.  The way I understand it I can't just print string.  I need to assign a variable each time it prints so ttk knows where each string goes.  That's what I was attempting to do with ("ls"+str(count)).set(storage(count - 1)) but that was clearly not working right.  I have just started using ttk.  Not very familiar with it yet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a `while` loop, you can just iterate using a for loop instead. As with Bemmu's answer this forces the characters to be all upper case, as it makes it easier. But you can modified a little more so it checks based on upper or lower case characters.

```
def shift(str):
    str =str.upper()
    for i in range(26):

        print "".join([chr((ord(x)-65+i)%26+65) for x in str])

shift("hello")
```

You can see this in operation here: http://codepad.org/OaBXM4s2